# Delegating reverse dns records - Bind (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: email-server, spam, reverse-dns, ptr-record, delegation

I have got a mail server attached to a static provided by my ISP. Our dns service is run by buddyns DNS service because our ISP blocked 53 by default. The DNS service is excellent, but i dont know how to set up ptr records and delegate it to buddy NS servers.

I am able to send and receive mail, but most of the mails sent to gmail accounts ends up as spam.

Could somebody help me with what can be done? I will be happy to help you with more information that you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control over the *reverse DNS zone*. Therefore, you simply can't configure the `PTR` record at BuddyDNS (or any other) *authoritative* name server for the *forward zone* of your domain.

You have two options:

1. Contact your ISP and ask whether it is possible to have custom `PTR` record for your IP or not. Because your ISP is blocking port `53` it might be an indicator the connection is not intended for hosting a DNS or even SMTP server. Therefore, the custom `PTR` might also be forbidden (or overpriced so nobody would buy it).

   If the latter is true, it's also possible that the IP range is reported as a dynamic IP range or a range that shouldn't have SMTP servers, e.g. the following [SORBS Zones Available](http://www.sorbs.net/general/using.shtml):

   ```
        dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net - Dynamic IP Address ranges (NOT a Dial Up list!)
   noserver.dnsbl.sorbs.net - IP addresses and Netblocks of where system administrators
                              and ISPs owning the network have indicated that servers
                              should not be present.
   ```
2. If there is ANY `PTR` record present with a corresponding `A` record i.e. you don't have a [SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch) but only [SMTP Banner Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check), you could modify your SMTP banner, instead. This is the part of the configuration you have direct control over.

Comment: I HAD A TALK WITH MY ISP TODAY AFTERNOON AFTER I PUT MY QUESTION AT SERVERFAULT. I WAS INFORMED THAT MY PORT 53 HAS BEEN OPENED AS PER MY REQUEST. BUT STILL MY REGISTRY SAYS THAT MY NAMESERVER COULD NOT BE CONNECTED OVER UDP, WHILE TCP IS REPORTED TO BE OPEN. THE ISP CONFIRMS THAT PORT 53 HAS BEEN FULLY OPEN AND NO FILTERS ARE IN PLACE.  WHAT CAN I DO?

Comment: If the ISP isn't blocking it, you might be (at a local firewall). But whether it's true or not, it won't solve your question here as you simply can't use _forward_ zone for modifying _reverse_ zone. These are two distinct issues.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. i have checked my firewall and confirmed twice that nothing is being blocked. i understand these are two distinct issues. but why cant my dns severs be contacted. I get the message " no child could be found".

Comment: That's impossible to test without knowing the IP address and impossible to guess with such little details.